# Intrinsical difference between struct and array in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct

everyone.

Here is a test program I wrote.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _item {
    int value;
} item , *pItem;

typedef struct _itemcontainer {
    pItem i;
} itemcontainer, *pItemcontainer;

int main(void) {
    item i;
    i.value = 1;

    pItem pi = &i;
    pItem* ppi = &pi;

    itemcontainer ei = {&i};
    pItem* pei = (pItem*)(&ei);

    pItem api[1] = {&i};

    printf("First case: %d\n", (*ppi)->value);
    printf("Second case: %d\n", (*pei)->value);
    printf("Third case: %d\n", (*api)->value);


    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The three printf functions' results are the same value, i.e. **1**. From the code, the initialization of variable **ei** and **api** are both **{&i}**. So I guess  **pItem* pei = (pItem*)ei** should work, however it failed. Could any one tell me the difference between **ei** and **api**? It seems to be related with how the compiler deal with struct and array, which I am not good at. I need a concrete explanation. Thanks in advance.

Best Wishes

Jfhu

Comment: Many people (myself included) think it's a bad practice to `typedef` pointer types. I use `typedef struct name name;` in which `struct name` can be an incomplete type if you want to restrict access to the members, so that `name *` is a pointer, and `const name *` is a pointer-to-`const`. I think it's clearer to use the language's given syntax for things like pointers and `const`s for this, because a naming scheme will be easier to forget (and harder to Google) than the built-in language syntax. If you use `name *`, good C programmers will _know_ without thinking that it needs to be cleaned up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that the array name is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element in most situations, while the name of an object of struct type is not.

The expression `pItem* pei = (pItem*)api;` would compile because it is equivalent to `pItem* pei = (pItem*)(&api[0]);`

The expression `pItem* pei = (pItem*)ei;` would not compile because it attempts to cast an object of struct type (a value) to a pointer to some unrelated type.

The expression you used, `pItem* pei = (pItem*)(&ei);` creates a pointer to the struct object and reinterprets it to mean pointer to pItem. Since pItem is the first element of the struct, it is located at the same memory address as `ei`, and this works. (this is even guaranteed by the standard, §6.7.2.1/13: "pointer to a structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member")

Comment: Well, as we all know, the meaning of the value of a pointer is a memory address. Could you tell me the meaning of the value of **ei**  (an object of struct type)?

Comment: @machinarium The value of the struct is the value of everything it contains. If you copy a struct that contains an array of 10 ints, you will physically copy ten ints (plus possible padding).

Comment: OK, I got it. The value of a pointer variable is a hex number,  which convinces me of the value of **ei** being a hex number also incorrectly. Upon debugging, I found the **value column** of **ei** in _Variables_ view of Eclipse is **{...}**, instead of a hex number. Now, I completely understand it. Thank you very much.